# Running two Apache Flink clusters on the same machine

Tags: cluster-computing, apache-flink, multi-user

I'd like to run two instances of Apache Flink on one machine, under separate unix users.

I already set different ports for `jobmanager.rpc.port` as well as `rest.port`, however when trying to start via `start-cluster.sh` it complains about alreay used addresses:

```
2019-04-04 13:48:08,218 INFO  akka.remote.Remoting                                          - Starting remoting
2019-04-04 13:48:08,226 INFO  akka.remote.Remoting                                          - Remoting started; listening on addresses :[akka.tcp://flink-metrics@localhost:43345]
2019-04-04 13:48:08,227 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint         - Actor system started at akka.tcp://flink-metrics@localhost:43345
2019-04-04 13:48:08,233 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.dispatcher.FileArchivedExecutionGraphStore  - Initializing FileArchivedExecutionGraphStore: Storage directory /tmp/executionGraphStore-dd135030-d700-4b52-8bda-4bcb7e0a7b35, expiration time 3600000, maximum
 cache size 52428800 bytes.
2019-04-04 13:48:08,269 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.blob.TransientBlobCache              - Created BLOB cache storage directory /tmp/blobStore-2f3c12d2-ae4f-4185-ae41-a4d845d5a3e8
2019-04-04 13:48:08,288 WARN  org.apache.flink.configuration.Configuration                  - Config uses deprecated configuration key 'jobmanager.rpc.address' instead of proper key 'rest.address'
2019-04-04 13:48:08,289 WARN  org.apache.flink.configuration.Configuration                  - Config uses deprecated configuration key 'web.address' instead of proper key 'rest.bind-address'
2019-04-04 13:48:08,290 WARN  org.apache.flink.runtime.dispatcher.DispatcherRestEndpoint    - Upload directory /tmp/flink-web-30ad01a5-24d0-47d0-b73e-6c9e0a2fab30/flink-web-upload does not exist, or has been deleted externally. Previously uploaded files are no longer available.
2019-04-04 13:48:08,291 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.dispatcher.DispatcherRestEndpoint    - Created directory /tmp/flink-web-30ad01a5-24d0-47d0-b73e-6c9e0a2fab30/flink-web-upload for file uploads.
2019-04-04 13:48:08,295 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.dispatcher.DispatcherRestEndpoint    - Starting rest endpoint.
2019-04-04 13:48:08,786 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.webmonitor.WebMonitorUtils           - Determined location of main cluster component log file: /home/ideventer/system/flink/flink-1.7.2/log/flink-ideventer-standalonesession-1-devsrv-java-1.log
2019-04-04 13:48:08,786 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.webmonitor.WebMonitorUtils           - Determined location of main cluster component stdout file: /home/ideventer/system/flink/flink-1.7.2/log/flink-ideventer-standalonesession-1-devsrv-java-1.out
2019-04-04 13:48:08,949 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.dispatcher.DispatcherRestEndpoint    - Shutting down rest endpoint.
2019-04-04 13:48:08,954 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint         - Shutting StandaloneSessionClusterEntrypoint down with application status FAILED. Diagnostics org.apache.flink.util.FlinkException: Could not create the DispatcherResourceManagerComponent.
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.component.AbstractDispatcherResourceManagerComponentFactory.create(AbstractDispatcherResourceManagerComponentFactory.java:242)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint.runCluster(ClusterEntrypoint.java:215)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint.lambda$startCluster$0(ClusterEntrypoint.java:163)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.security.NoOpSecurityContext.runSecured(NoOpSecurityContext.java:30)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint.startCluster(ClusterEntrypoint.java:162)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint.runClusterEntrypoint(ClusterEntrypoint.java:517)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.StandaloneSessionClusterEntrypoint.main(StandaloneSessionClusterEntrypoint.java:65)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
        at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketChannel.doBind(NioServerSocketChannel.java:128)
        at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.bind(AbstractChannel.java:558)
        at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1358)
        at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeBind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:501)
        at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.bind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:486)
        at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1019)
        at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.bind(AbstractChannel.java:254)
        at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.bootstrap.AbstractBootstrap$2.run(AbstractBootstrap.java:366)
        at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:163)
        at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:404)
        at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:463)
        at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:884)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
.
2019-04-04 13:48:08,958 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.blob.BlobServer                      - Stopped BLOB server at 0.0.0.0:60277
2019-04-04 13:48:08,959 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.blob.TransientBlobCache              - Shutting down BLOB cache
2019-04-04 13:48:08,970 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcService              - Stopping Akka RPC service.
2019-04-04 13:48:08,973 INFO  akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider$RemotingTerminator         - Shutting down remote daemon.
2019-04-04 13:48:08,973 INFO  akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider$RemotingTerminator         - Shutting down remote daemon.
2019-04-04 13:48:08,975 INFO  akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider$RemotingTerminator         - Remote daemon shut down; proceeding with flushing remote transports.
2019-04-04 13:48:08,975 INFO  akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider$RemotingTerminator         - Remote daemon shut down; proceeding with flushing remote transports.
2019-04-04 13:48:08,997 INFO  akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider$RemotingTerminator         - Remoting shut down.
2019-04-04 13:48:09,010 INFO  akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider$RemotingTerminator         - Remoting shut down.
2019-04-04 13:48:09,028 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcService              - Stopped Akka RPC service.
2019-04-04 13:48:09,032 ERROR org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint         - Could not start cluster entrypoint StandaloneSessionClusterEntrypoint.
org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypointException: Failed to initialize the cluster entrypoint StandaloneSessionClusterEntrypoint.
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint.startCluster(ClusterEntrypoint.java:181)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint.runClusterEntrypoint(ClusterEntrypoint.java:517)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.StandaloneSessionClusterEntrypoint.main(StandaloneSessionClusterEntrypoint.java:65)
Caused by: org.apache.flink.util.FlinkException: Could not create the DispatcherResourceManagerComponent.
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.component.AbstractDispatcherResourceManagerComponentFactory.create(AbstractDispatcherResourceManagerComponentFactory.java:242)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint.runCluster(ClusterEntrypoint.java:215)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint.lambda$startCluster$0(ClusterEntrypoint.java:163)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.security.NoOpSecurityContext.runSecured(NoOpSecurityContext.java:30)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint.startCluster(ClusterEntrypoint.java:162)
        ... 2 more
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
        at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketChannel.doBind(NioServerSocketChannel.java:128)
        at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.bind(AbstractChannel.java:558)
        at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1358)
        at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeBind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:501)
        at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.bind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:486)
        at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1019)
        at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.bind(AbstractChannel.java:254)
        at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.bootstrap.AbstractBootstrap$2.run(AbstractBootstrap.java:366)
        at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:163)
        at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:404)
        at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:463)
        at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:884)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

What other options must be set so that the second instance can be started?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried this myself, but looking through https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.7/ops/config.html searching for "port" I find a few places where it says things like "It is recommended to set a range of ports to avoid collisions".

Take a look at [taskmanager.rpc.port](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.7/ops/config.html#taskmanager-rpc-port) and [metrics.internal.query-service.port](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.7/ops/config.html#metrics-internal-query-service-port) for starters. The queryable state and blob server ports might also be a factor -- not sure.

Comment: Okay so I added dedicated port config for `taskmanager.rpc.port`, `metrics.internal.query-service.port`, `taskmanager.data.port`, `blob.server.port` and `query.server.ports`, and still get the same error. The error indicates that the "cluster entrypoint" port is already used, however there seems to be no config parameter related to a "cluster entrypoint".